# Identifying rings of bounded functions

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the inequalities
$$0\le\sqrt{2}x-y<1.$$
The set of polynomials in the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ that are bounded on $S$ obviously forms a subring $B$. I suspect that $B=\mathbb{R}[\sqrt{2}x-y]$.  Can anyone suggest a proof or a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X \mapsto \sqrt{2}x - y$ and $Y \mapsto y$ defines an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]$ to $\mathbb{R}[x, y]$. In  $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]$ you are asking which polynomials are bounded in the strip $0 \le X < 1$. But if $f = f(X, Y)$ is bounded for $X = 1/2$ say, all the coefficients of $Y$ must vanish,  hence $f \in \mathbb{R}[X]$. Your claim now follows by pulling this back into $\mathbb{R}[x, y]$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion $\mathbb R[\sqrt 2 x-y]\subseteq B$ is clear.
Consider the algebra homomorphism $\phi\colon \mathbb R[x,y]\to\mathbb R[t]$ given by $x\mapsto t$, $y\mapsto \sqrt 2 t$.
The kernel of $\phi$ is precisely $\mathbb R[\sqrt 2 x-y]$.
Let $f\in B$. We want to show $\phi(f)=0$.
Assume $\phi(f)\ne 0$.
Then $\phi(f)$ is not bounded and for each $M$ we can pick $\tau_M\in\mathbb R$ with $|\phi(f)(\tau_M)|>M$.
But then also 
$|f(\sqrt 2\tau_M,\tau_M)|=|\phi(f)(\tau_M)|>M$ with $(\sqrt 2\tau_M,\tau_M)\in S$, i.e. $f$ is not bounded on $S$.

Comment: The kernel of $\phi$ cannot be a subring: For example, clearly $1\in B$, but $\phi(1)\ne 0$.